# Base64 is not decoded properly

Tags: php, android, bitmap

I know this question has been asked alot of times but I couldn't find the right solution. What I am doing here is that there are a total of 7 images on server. Server gets contents of each one of these and then converts it into base64. It then sends each one of these strings one by one back to android client. Following is code:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, my_url,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearView);

    int index=0;

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String s) {
        //Disimissing the progress dialog

        loading.dismiss();
        //Showing toast message of the response
        // Toast.makeText(DisplayResults.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("nofatima"+s);
        ImageView layout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.m0);

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(s.replace("/",""), Base64.DEFAULT);

        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        layout.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        layout.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte, decodedByte.getWidth(), decodedByte.getHeight(), false));
```

This is the Base64 which is being returned by the server

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBAQFBAYFBQYJBgUGCQsIBgYICwwKCgsKCgwQDAwMDAwMEAwODxAPDgwTExQUExMcGxsbHB8fHx8fHx8fHx//2wBDAQcHB
```

There is ofcourse more string but I am not adding whole of it here. This is the error that I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fatima.cgir, PID: 6811
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
    at com.example.fatima.cgir.DisplayResults$1.onResponse(DisplayResults.java:91)
    at com.example.fatima.cgir.DisplayResults$1.onResponse(DisplayResults.java:76)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I do realize that this exception is because I am replacing / with "" but when I don't add this statement it returns null exception. Which I'm guessing is because it is not being decoded properly. What could be the issue?

Comment: Any problems, errors or exceptions?

Comment: I did specify the error in the question.

Comment: There is no question as far as i can see. And you are not mentioning errors in your post. And even if you had you should now have elaborated.

Comment: Ok let me add details

Comment: If there are errors or exceptions you should mention them in your post. If you have questions you should put them in your post.